# How to create multiple admin dashboard template in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I  have recently purchased an admin dashboard template from themeforest.
Here is the link 
http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/

I have to create four different admin panel for admin, affiliation, supplier and customers.

So, I need to create a cms and also integrate the data like graphs , chart etc.
Is it possible to use wordpress as a cms in the project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that altering your thinking would solve the problem.

You don't need four admin templates, but you need one admin template (as WP supports) that you need to change accordingly to a specific user.